# Looking for answer about Clean URLs that I have not found thus far

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

I am looking to clean up my URLs and I am having the most difficult time. I have an Apache server on GoDaddy. Not sure if hosting is the problem. I've uploaded many `.htaccess` files and none have worked.

Goal: I am trying to eliminate ".php" completely from my site.

Example: `http://example.com/about.php` and `http://example.com/folder/anotherpage.php`

I want it to read `http://example.com/about` and `http://example.com/folder/anotherpage`

How do I write a `.htaccess` file for this? All of the answers I've found deal more with parameters.

and nothing I've done seems to work. Is this a GoDaddy issue? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule about about.php
RewriteRule folder/anotherpage folder/anotherpage.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but this did not work for me. This thing is killing me!